# Pygame get name of colided sprite

Tags: python, pygame

For my game written in pygame, I need to detect collision.

For this is use  pygame.sprite.spritecollide(), which give me a list of the colided sprite. However, their name isn't quite undertandable:
here are 2 colided sprite
[image]

How do I get the real name of the sprite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not clear what your purpose is, the most obvious solution to me would be to just add a name parameter to each sprite.  Then after the collision, you can do:

```
for sprite in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, group1):
    print(sprite.name)
    if sprite.name == 'foo':
        # do whatever
```

For this to work, in your sprite code, you need to define the parameter:

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # <your other sprite code>
        self.name = name
```

Then, when you create the sprite, you pass in a name:

```
sprite1 = MySprite('test sprite')
```

Comment: I assumed you knew how to add a `name' property to the sprite.  I updated the answer.